# Runas combined with taskkill different in Server 2016 than in Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, runas

GD,

I have used the following command succesfully in Server 2012 R2, but it does not work in Server 2016:

**runas /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\administrator "taskkill /f /im name_of_service.exe"**

Anybody any idea what has changed in Server 2016?

If I want to close something like notepad.exe that works. 
But not spoolsv.exe for example

**runas /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\administrator "taskkill /im spoolsv.exe /f"**

Whereas when I run:
**taskkill /im spoolsv.exe /f**
That does work.

So it seems to be the combination of Server 2016, runas and taskkill what has changed.

No error message to be found anywhere.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Probably help if any errors/results were included.

Comment: You tried it in Server 2016, and it worked? I would of course post errors, but there are none. Not displayed in the CMD window or in Windows Event Log.

I know it doesn't work because I can see the process not being closed.

Comment: Put `cmd /k ` before taskkill. If you are killing a service, my guess would be it is restarting due to recovery action.

Comment: No this is not the case. I also have taskmanager open so I can see in server 2012 it's actually closing/ not in the list anymore, this does not happen in server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Admin Approval Mode was Enabled in a GPO. So I disabled that and after that everything worked again.